# Хорошая книга по C

Tags: c, книги

Решил учить азы языка C. Кто-нибудь может посоветовать хорошую книгу? Друг дал  почитать "M. Уэйт, С. Прата, Д. Мартин - Язык Си руководство для начинающих", но эта книга старше меня.

Comment: Начинайте сразу с С++(С с классами). В.В.Подбельский, "Язык С++". Мне очень пригодилась.

Comment: @BuilderC Вопрос был про C. А C++ или C-- -- это, видимо, не так актуально.

Comment: На самом деле, для студента актуально. Просто незная с чего начать, предпочитаю обращаться к азам.

Comment: не советую В.В.Подбельский, морально устарело, как в анекдоте с двумя плюсами: 
- почему язык называется Си ++?
- да потому-что это постинкрементный СИ: работают на Си++, а программируют как на Си.

Comment: Ддя начинающих на С++ советую Шилдт, любая книга. Страуструп - немного нудно, но тоже полезно. Однозначно в книге должна рассматриваться STL.
Для программирования на Си - Уэйт Прата Мартин Язык Си
Керниган, Ричи. язык Си, руководство для начинающих.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Подкину несколько наименований полезных книг, правда с точки зрения преподавателя ;)

- [K. N. King. C Programming: A Modern Approach, 2nd Edition](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Modern-Approach-2nd-Edition/dp/0393979504/).
  На мой взгляд лучший учебник по языку C, покрывающий C99. Разобраны все 24 заголовочных файла стандартной библиотеки C99 с таким уровнем детализации, которого я больше не видел нигде. Является основным учебником по программированию на языке C во многих американских колледжах. К сожалению на русский язык книга не переводилась, но 100-мегабайтный PDF английского издания легко находится в сети.
- [Manuel Bermudez. Study Guide for C Programming: A Modern Approach](http://www.amazon.com/Study-Guide-Programming-Modern-Approach/dp/0393969460/).
  Руководство к описанному выше учебнику. На русском также не найти.
- [Randal Bryant and David O'Hallaron. Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective (2nd Edition)](http://www.amazon.com/Computer-Systems-Programmers-Perspective-Edition/dp/0136108040/).
  Эту книгу я упоминал здесь уже несколько раз. Она не о языке C - она об архитектуре компьютера и поведении компилятора с точки зрения программиста на C. В ней можно найти ответы на такие вопросы как "почему компилятор как правило преобразует циклы к форме do-while?", "как использовать switch, чтобы его машинная реализация была эффективней каскадного if?", "как работает компоновщик?", "почему оптимизирующий компилятор не может соптимизировать казалось бы очевидный код и как писать код, чтобы получить максимум от оптимизации?" и многие другие. Издавалась на русском языке ограниченным тиражом, английский вариант элементарно находится в сети.
- [Stephen Kochan. Programming in C (3rd Edition)](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-3rd-Edition-Stephen-Kochan/dp/0672326663/).
  Хороший, добротный учебник. Издавался на русском языке.
- [Richard Heathfield and Lawrence Kirby. C Unleashed](http://www.amazon.com/C-Unleashed-Richard-Heathfield/dp/0672318962/).
  Философская книга для уже знающих язык. Должна быть на книжной полке каждого программиста на языке C. На русском языке издавалась под названием "Искусство программирования на C", несложно найти PDF/DJVU. Дик Хэзфилд также широко известен своими статьями по глубокому исследованию проблем программирования на языке C (примерно как Андрей Александреску на C++).

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, на данный момент лучшая книга по С для начинающих - Стивен Прата "Язык программирования С". K&R, конечно, классика, но написан суховато и слишком сжато, для новичков (особенно не профессионалов в IT) будет трудноват. Потом можно почитать замечательную книжку Харбисона и Стила "Язык С с примерами". Это прекрасный учебник и  справочник по С99.

Comment: Поддерживаю, K&R надо читать, но не сразу. Учебник Прата неплохой. Жаль по C он остановился на пятом издании, а по C++ уже (в конце 2011) опубликовал шестое, покрывающее C++11.

Answer (score 2):

Керниган, Ритчи "Язык программирования Си". Правда первое издание (и первый перевод) вышли ещё раньше вышеуказанного "Руководства для начинающих", но -- классика.

Comment: А причем тут первое издание? Уже вышло, наверное, двадцать с лишним изданий, и каждый раз что-то изменялось.

Comment: у меня за 2012 год книга, 34 издание)

Answer (score 2):

Керниган, Ритчи "Язык программирования Си" - толковая книга и от авторов самого языка. В русском переводе есть и более поздние издания. Всё объясняется на примерах и в конце каждой главые есть упражнения. Можно и в .djvu, и в .chm скачать. Также в придачку можно скачать: Керниган Б., Ритчи Д., Фьэр А.
"Язык программирования Си. Задачи по языку Си". Там есть примеры с объяснениями.

Answer (score 2):

Ворожцов А. В., Винокуров Н. А. [Алгоритмы: Построение, анализ и реализация на языке программирования Си](http://forcoder.ru/algorithm/algoritmy-postroenie-analiz-i-realizaciya-na-yazyke-programmirovaniya-si-719)

Первую часть книги можно пропустить если Вас интересует только синтаксис, но вообще не стоит, очень хорошая база дается.

В книжном варианте: [Практика и теория программирования. В 2 книгах. Книга 2](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5039922/)

Answer (score 0):

Я учил C (обучение еще, конечно, не окончено =)) по книгам **Харви Дейтел, Пол Дейтел "Как программировать на C"** и **Герберт Шилдт "Полный справочник по C++"** (там C идет как подраздел). Все описано в них простым языком и, думаю, для начала в самый раз.

Comment: Вообще-то книга Дейтелов называется "Как программировать на C++". А учить С по книге о С++ - неправильно. Это идеологически разные языки, несмотря на все общности. Кроме того, множество языка С не полностью входит в множество языка С++